# Do pesticides containing EDCs cause IQ loss, obesity and cryptorchidism?

Tags: environmental-health, pesticides

Recently, there have been news reports about Endochrine-Disrupting Chemicals (EDCs) have sprung up, such as [this February 2015 Guardian article](http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2015/may/22/eu-dropped-pesticide-laws-due-to-us-pressure-over-ttip-documents-reveal).

> Draft EU criteria could have banned 31 pesticides containing endocrine disrupting chemicals (EDCs). But these were dumped amid fears of a trade backlash stoked by an aggressive US lobby push, access to information documents obtained by Pesticides Action Network (PAN) Europe show. [...]
>
> The result was that legislation planned for 2014 was kicked back until at least 2016, despite estimated health costs of €150bn per year in Europe from endocrine-related illnesses such as IQ loss, obesity and cryptorchidism – a condition affecting the genitals of baby boys.

Do the pesticides cause the health detriments mentioned: IQ loss, obesity and cryptorchidism?

Comment: What is incomplete about the links in that report especially the first one? which has a link to this peer reviewed paper http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2014/11/13/aje.kwu285.abstract#

Comment: @Mark: That paper is about sunscreen and fertility. Is it relevant?